# Update SQL value

Tags: sql

I have a field name citation that have values C12345, C23456 etc. I need to update the citation field so all citations now have a 0 after the C.

```
Update account
set citation = 
where citation like 'C%'
```

Comment: Is that all I need?  Seems like there would be more to it

Comment: So you need to turn `C12345` into `C012345`?

Comment: paqogomez answer looks right to be down there. But make sure you use the right function in the platform. replace in SQL Server might not work for mysql for example.

Comment: What about cases with leading zeros right after the `C` (e.g. `C00123`. Are those relevant to you? Do values have a fixed length (e.g. 6 chars, not more and not less)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace should work for this:

```
Update account
set citation = replace(citation, 'C', 'C0')
where citation like 'C%'
```

I have used [sql server replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) syntax here.  Other platforms may be different.

As pointed out by @sjagr in the comments

> To be safe of values already set to C0, perhaps it should be `where citation not like 'C0%' AND citation like 'C%'`

Comment: To be safe of values already set to `C0`, perhaps it should be `where citation not like 'C0%' AND citation like 'C%'` However there could be native values like `C01234` where the `0` padding is still desired.

Comment: The `substring` function is better than the `replace` function based on the fact that the `substring` function will leave the remaining text (after "C" or "C0") untouched, where the `replace` function has the power to change any "C" character if finds.

Answer (score 4):

Try following.

```
Update account
set citation = 'C0' + substring(citation, 2, len(citation))
where citation like 'C%'
```

Comment: Please do not add superfluous text to a question just to say you've edited a post.  Thats bad form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat the statement, you'll need to prevent the changed lines to be candidate for the next time you would run the same statement:

```
update account
   set citation = 'C0' + substring(citation, 2, len(citation))
 where citation like 'C%' 
   and citation NOT like 'C0%';
```